# Epicor Crystal Reports Data

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, epicorerp

I have a standard crystal report from Epicor loaded into Visual Studio (specifically the purchase order report). Basically I would like to preview the purchase order for order #12345. How can I do this? It seems like the report data source is already setup although it doesn't seem to point to a database. This is the regular report that comes with Epicor. Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for Epicor reports comes from a process that queries the database and generates either XML files (E9) or tables in a separate database (E10). As you are using Crystal Reports I assume you are using E9, as it is still supported in E10 but SSRS is standard.

You will need to run the report in Epicor and allow the Task agent to pick up the job to produce the data. You should then be able to use the XML files to provide data to your report designer.